# Insert into ms access database without knowing the datatype

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-insert

Is this possible with ms access data type?

I need to merge mdb files. The twist is i doesn't know the table names and the data type.

I'm now in the part of merging data. What i did is i retrieve the data first then save in the merged mdb file.

Here is my code

```
string SqlString = "Insert Into Contacts (data1, data2) Values (?,?)";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data1", "data1");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data2", "data2");
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

With the code above i can save the data using if the data type is text. But when the `data type` is int and the data i passed is string but can be parsed as number the gives me `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

If i'm going to parse number. How about the `Date/Time` format? I check the database and it's also one of the error. How can i pass null into this? i checked the value and it's blank.

Comment: Just use `int.Parse()` or `Convert.ToInt32()` methods if the string is parseable to int, e.g. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data1", Convert.ToInt32(data1));`

Comment: You need to know the DataType of your columns. There are too many possibilities to write the data wrongly even when you don't have immediate errors. The db engine is forced to try a conversion from the input string to whatever is the expected type and this could go wrong at many levels.

Comment: But, how do you load your data initially? If you load your data in a DataTable then you know the DataType expected by the destination table. They should be the same

Comment: so a solution is use a data table then insert the data table? in the database?

Comment: @Steve can you please provide a snippet. How to save the result of select statement or data table into my new database? i've been trying this but i can't make things work

Comment: Yes, probably but you haven't explained how do you create the datatable on the target database. Is it already there? Are the datatable's schemas identical?

Comment: Because what i do is merging. So the mdb files to be merged and tables are identical. I copy the first mdb file. And execute delete query. Then this is where i save the merged data